# JavaScript: Get property with largest numerical value in object

Tags: javascript

I have an object like so:

```
const obj = {
    happy: 0.6,
    neutral: 0.1,
    said: 0.3
}
```

How do I get the property with the largest value (happy in this case)?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  Hint: You can loop over properties on an object in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const obj = {
  happy: 0.6,
  neutral: 0.1,
  said: 0.3,
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])?.[0]?.[0];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key-value pairs, and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the property with the largest value:

```js
const obj = { happy: 0.6, neutral: 0.1, said: 0.3 };

const propWithLargestValue = Object.entries(obj).reduce((prop, [key,val]) =>
  val > (obj[prop] || Number.MIN_VALUE) ? key : prop
, null);

console.log(propWithLargestValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the entries of the object and find the max value. You can then take those same entries and locate the first entry with that value.

```js
const maxValue = obj => (entries =>
  (max => entries.find(([k, v]) => v === max))
  (Math.max(...entries.map(([key, val]) => val))))
(Object.entries(obj));

const obj = {
  happy: 0.6,
  neutral: 0.1,
  said: 0.3
};

const [ key, value ] = maxValue(obj);

console.log(key);   // happy
console.log(value); // 0.6
```

### Code golf

The following function can be reduced to 86 bytes.

```js
f=o=>(e=>(m=>e.find(([,x])=>x===m))(Math.max(...e.map(([,v])=>v))))(Object.entries(o))
```